# Encoding decoding bytes

Tags: c, sockets, encoding, embedded, decoding

I have an embedded device which sends me UTC date in this format (date is 4 bytes):

```
 buffer.push_back((BYTE)(time_utc & 0x000000FF));
 buffer.push_back((BYTE)((time_utc & 0x0000FF00) >> 8));
 buffer.push_back((BYTE)((time_utc & 0x00FF0000) >> 16));
 buffer.push_back((BYTE)((time_utc & 0xFF000000) >> 24));
```

On the server I am receiving the bytes and storing them in `socket_buf`, starting from index 0-3 and decoding it using the following logic

```
mypkt.dateTime = ( ( socket_buf[0] << 24) +  
(socket_buf[1 ] << 16) +  socket_buf[2] << 8) + 
(socket_buf[3] << 0));
```

But I am not sure if am decoding it properly because the date I get is not correct. Can anyone suggest me the correct way of decoding it? I am decoding the date using the Linux command (16711840 is the number I get by decoding):

```
#date -d @16711840
```

Comment: both machines are the endian-ness ?

Comment: I think this has to do with byte ordering in networks. The network byte order is big endian and most intel processors are little endian => this is where the error may be. Did you look at C functions `htons()` and `ntohs()` ?

Comment: But i am sending other data also, which i am about to extract correctly, i am more concered with my logic as to i am decoding it correct from the socket_buf. I am not sure if I need to do &-ing as they did on the device.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `socket_buf`, it could be the cause of the bug.

Comment: socket_buf is declated as unsigned char*

Comment: On the server side you are converting it the wrong way. It should be: (sock_buf[3] << 24) + (sock_buf[2] << 16) + (sock_buff[1] << 8) + sock_buf[0];

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Did you clear your socket_buf?

Did you make sure that your computer is big enddian?

Also, I give you a suggestion : using or operator instead of plus.

This could save you more time.

```
mypkt.dateTime = (long) ( ( socket_buf[0] << 24) |  (socket_buf[1] << 16) |  socket_buf[2] << 8) | (socket_buf[3] << 0));
```

Comment: The code in the original post is endian-independent. Bitwise OR is equivalent with addition. There should be no performance difference with optimizer enabled (but OR might be easier to read and understand in this case). Also, your suggested method doesn't work if `socket_buf` is of the wrong integer type. And the cast to signed long is pointless and irrational.

Comment: Yes the socket buffer is clear. Lundin so you mean to say that i don't need to do &-ing as it was did in the original code from the device

Comment: This code seems to work fine for me:    mypkt.dateTime = ( ( socket_buf[HB_PKT_DATE_TIME] << 0) +  (socket_buf[HB_PKT_DATE_TIME +1 ] << 8) +  (socket_buf[HB_PKT_DATE_TIME+2] << 16) + (socket_buf[HB_PKT_DATE_TIME+3] << 24));

Comment: @Rohit yes, that's equivalent to the code in _my_ answer - this answer still has the endianness decoding the wrong way around.

Comment: @Rohit It probably works just fine until you happen to have a byte value larger than 0x7F.

Answer (score 8):

The writing code is *little endian* - it's sending the least significant byte first.

Your reading code is expecting *big endian* - it's taking the zeroth byte and shifting it left by 24 bits.

Note that in neither case is the code dependent on the local machine's endianness - the code as written is independent of that, it's just that they're not consistent with each other.

Try this, instead:

```
mypkt.dateTime = ((socket_buf[0] <<  0) +
                  (socket_buf[1] <<  8) + 
                  (socket_buf[2] << 16) +
                  ((uint32_t)socket_buf[3] << 24));
```

The cast is necessary (but only on the last shift) because `0x80 - 0xff` will be converted to a *`signed int`* and it's undefined what happens to bits that are shifted into the sign bit (thanks @Lundin)

NB: 16711840 isn't a "current" Unix epoch date-time value whichever endianness you use to represent it.  You may have other problems elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `socket_buf` is declared unsigned char, `socket_buf[0] << 24` is a bug.

`socket_buf[0]` is unsigned char and will get integer promoted to an `int`. Whether that is 16 bits or 32 bits on this specific system doesn't matter, because the program will crash no matter. In both cases, it ends up as a signed variable. You will left shift a signed variable and shift binary ones into the sign bits. Then you do addition on this.

The correct way to write the decoding is this:

```
mypkt.dateTime = ( ((uint32_t)socket_buf[0] << 24) |
                   ((uint32_t)socket_buf[1] << 16) |
                   ((uint32_t)socket_buf[2] <<  8) |
                   ((uint32_t)socket_buf[3] <<  0) );
```

Also, you seem to change the byte order backwards between encoding and decoding. I don't quite see what that has to do with endianess, your code is simply using an inconsistent order between `buffer` versus`sock_buf`.

Comment: surely an `unsigned char` will get promoted to an `_unsigned_ int`?  And in either event, it won't cause a crash.

Comment: OK, clarification - since `0 - 0xff` both fit inside an `int`, it will indeed be promoted to `int` rather than `uint`, but _this will not cause sign extension_.  The resulting `int` will still have the range `0 - 0xff`.

Comment: @Alnitak It will be promoted to an int, _not_ to unsigned int (C11 6.3.1.1). And if the int is 32 bits, you would essentially get this code: `int32_t my_int=0xFF; my_int << 24;` which is undefined behavior, as per C11 6.5.7.

Comment: right - the very top most bit might get lost (depending on the implementation).